# Project management software with Mercurial support that runs on PHP/JSP servers

Tags: pm-software

Our business uses Mercurial for SCM and use it's integrated server for push and pull operations. We are also familiar with Apache+PHP and Tomcat+J2EE applications.

I am looking out for a project management software that integrates with Mercurial (and takes in the PUSH/PULL operations with authentication).

I am looking for something that isnt **too much hassle to setup** and also on a platform that I am already familiar (Apache or Tomcat) with. Redmine loses here as I need to know to setup Apache+mod_passenger.

Please mention choices that are either:

1. easy to set up and use
2. matches my familiarity with PHP and Tomcat

Comment: Why can't you install Mercurial itself?

Comment: hmm that fact should have been obvious from 1st sentence. Did a minor edit

Comment: Software recommendations...

Comment: @SergeyKudryavtsev  Are you saying such questions are no longer allowed? Please then vote to close. This is an old question.

Answer (score 1):

[Projelead](http://www.projelead.com) is a web based project management software, PHP based, that can run on tomcat.

Projelead comes in two versions standard (open source) and enterprise (commercial).

take a look at it and see if it can match your needs.

good luck!

Link: [www.projelead.com](http://www.projelead.com)

Answer (score 0):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) has Mercurial support: [TracMercurial](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMercurial).

Answer (score 0):

[RhodeCode](http://rhodecode.org/) - not PHP or Tomcat (Python, Pylons-based), but nicely fit to req. 1 "easy to set up and use"